# How to get rows form table that each email appear one time

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm having a hard time getting the right row from my table.
I'm trying to get some rows by finding emails and i want to get the last email sent to them.
My query is:

```
select *
from persons p2, (
SELECT p.id,p.name,p.email
FROM persons p, emails e
WHERE p.id = e.person_id
) a
where a.email = p2.email
```

This query return the list of all the email sent to persons.

Can someone help me with this query, the query need to return list of persons with emails, but each email need to appear one time.

Thanks

Comment: How do you determine which email is last?

Comment: Ok, based on what do you determine that it is the last email?

Comment: by time, i have time_sent column

Comment: What are you using mssql 2000, mssql 2005, mssql 2008, mysql??

Comment: If you provide us columns stored in each database, it would be much easier to help.

Comment: this tables really simple, holds the sent emails with time and person id. And persons table holds name, birthday, username, password....

Comment: Can you try the option that I suggested?

Comment: yep, doesn't work, sorry

Comment: Well, it should. Can you execute the inner query? Does it return correct list of emails?

Comment: i already tried this query...i think i will try to write function or procedure...i need to many things from this query. thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this variant:

```
select p.*, tmp.email
  from persons p, (select person_id, email
                     from emails e1
                    where not exists (
                          select 1
                            from emails e2
                           where e1.person_id = e2.person_id
                             and e1.time_sent < e2.time_sent)) tmp
 where p.id = tmp.person_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you DBMS supports ctes you can do something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY time_sent DESC) AS iRank,
    e.email,
    e.person_id
FROM
    email AS e
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    persons AS p
    LEFT JOIN CTE
        ON p.id=CTE.person_id
        AND CTE.iRank=1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select *
from persons, (SELECT p.id, m.mail, max(m.time_sent) 
               from persons as p, emails as m 
               where m.mail = p.mail
               GROUP BY p.id, m.mail) as a
where persons.id = a.id
```